# DomPdf produces a blank page, regardless the given HTML

Tags: pdf, composer-php, dompdf, php-8

There are quite a few questions here on SO regarding this matter, but OP's either quit on getting it work, or have accepted an answer that doesn't work in my case.

I even opened a new [issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2406) for it, but I'll copy the exact contents of it here:

No matter how much I tone down my HTML string given to `loadHTML()` the `stream()` method yields a single blank page.

The following should produce a single white page with a word "Content" written in the top left corner.

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$domPdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
$domPdf->loadHtml(<<<HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>PDF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Content
    </body>
    </html>
HTML
);
$domPdf->stream();
```

I even tried with the following line

```php
$domPdf->loadHtml('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>PDF</title></head><body>Content</body></html>');
```

My composer looks like this if it matters. A completely fresh project.

```json
{
    "name": "vendor/project",
    "description": "Description",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "Private",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Me",
            "email": "my@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "spatie/ray": "^1.21",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Local development with Windows10 / Laragon / Apache / PHP 8.0.0 (no framework).

Attached the resulting file.
[document.pdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/files/6117093/document.pdf)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this even related to PHP8 or Composer? Have you tried calling `$domPdf->render()`, as written in the documentation?

Comment: I'm such a dumb dumb. I somehow misunderstood the docs, and thought you *either* use `render()` to be able to save a file on server *or* use `stream()` for browser to download it immediately. Thank you! Now I just have to figure out how to rename it and save it.